# Rotation and common absolute coordinate system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Got an interesting observation a couple of days earlier, could you please comment it or point to some mistake.

As everyone knows, there are lots of stars in our universe. 
Stars are in common just big amounts of self-gravitating collapsed spheres of hot gas and plasma.

If this kind of sphere is rotating, then its rotation can be measured by its poles collapse. It means we can easily make a photo of it, calculate difference between equatorial and polar radiuses and get its rotation speed.

So a rotation of any star can be easily detected.
This rotation is measured relative to some kind of absolute inertial non-rotating coordinate system, same for all stars.

Since a rotation can be detected, then a simple line movement can be detected also (just speed, correlated with rotation of a closest star).

That means that there is a common absolute inertial coordinate system (a kind of a base one), in which every star is rotating.

But getting this special base system is not common to physics and it is a little bit confusing to me.

Is there really that kind of special absolute coordinate system, or it is just some logical paradox type of stuff ?

Comment: Your proposal only works if all the stars are moving (moving, not rotating) with the same velocity. Otherwise there's no common inertial frame. And even if they were, that wouldn't change the fact that *the laws of physics* work the same in all inertial frames.

Comment: Laws of physics are same, that's for sure.  The fun thing as about some special base or absolute space inertial coordinate system, which is a little bit confusing (there is no mention about that in common books).